# Do I need to synchronize an asynchronous method?

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, synchronization

I have a statesless session bean like this:

```
@Stateless
public class ObjectProcessor
{        
    private CallBackObject callback;
    private Ojbect object;

    @Asynchronous
    public void process(CallBackObject callback, Object object)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.object= object;

        // call private method one
        // call private method two
        // call private method three

        callback.receiveUpdatedObject(object);
    }
}
```

where the private methods all do some processing which updates `object`.  Do I have to worry about synchronizing the asynchronous process method to ensure that there are no issues with setting the CallBackObject and Object as class variables?  I think it's okay as is, but am having doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stateless bean will live as long as the asynchronous call lives. No other bean client will share that bean instance, so you dont have to worry about using `@Asynchronous`